# Hiding text with a "0" value

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to hide an HTML field based on the displayed value of "0"
I have an ecomm site that displays Quantity available with a numeric value.
I only want to display the number if it is above "0"
The values are populated from data base upload to the site.
The "0" value is NOT an input field. so most codes I see have the solution with some sort of input condition code.

```
<span id="availability" class="product_availability availability-item"><p style="color: crimson; display: contents">Call for Availability. </p></span>
<span style="display: inline;" id="product_inventory">0</span>
```

My site displays this: Call for Availability.0
If item has QTY above "0" it displays this: Qty On Hand: 1708
I need to remove the "0" and only display Call for Availability.

I have researched similar request on this forum and found all have answers using an input field. The problem is the "0" is not an input. It is an code generated inventory amount.

I have tried CSS to hide the value, but that hides ALL the values including above "0".

I can insert any form of code needed. Java, PHP, json, etc...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unQms.jpg)

Comment: HTML alone won't be able to hide anything beyond using <noscript> or style="display:none;" attribute.  You need to specify what programming language you're trying to solve this problem with.   Could be raw javascript, could be typescript, could be PHP?

Comment: Does the number in string `QTY AVAILABLE: 12` have it's own class or div ?

Comment: I have an open source page to add a script or snippet.

Comment: What have You tried as far? Using js you can use innerHTML to change Your node value

Comment: Here is the section that displays the message.
<div id="availabilityInfo" class="availabilityInfo"> 
<span class="availability-header">[product_Header-availability]</span> <span id="availability" class="product_availability availability-item">[availability]</span> 
<!-- this is the QTY Number  [stock] -->
<span style="display: inline;" id="product_inventory">[stock]</span> 

<span class="freeshipping availability-item"><!--[freeshipping]--></span> 
<!--END: freeshippingblock--> 
</div>

Comment: I've tried multiple snippets and css answers from mutiple forums.

Comment: First of all i'll suggest to read [ask] and [mcve], then post here what you have tried, explaining for example how do you obtaine the QTY AVAILABLE, is it a dynamic value coming from some script?

Comment: Please also include the source code in your original question to help others understand. HTML alone cannot compare a value to 0. We have to know the technology used, for example which template engine this is.

Comment: Peter, Not sure what you mean by template engine. I am using 3dcart e-commerce retail software. It is open source which will allow me to add JS PHP and more. 
The software uses [TAGS] to display data. I tried the .JS script below and it only added an input box with a 0 in it.

Comment: Consider editing your question to provide the additional information being requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you use input tag , you need to create a fuction on javascipt ,  Here is html line :

```
<input id="num" type=number value="0" onchange="valChange(this);"/>

function valChange(obj){
      if(obj.value=="0"){
        obj.style.color="#fff"
      } else{
        obj.style.color="#000"
      }
    }
```